# Trying to match the first of two series of characters in a string in python

Tags: python, regex

Trying to match the first instance of either "foo" or "bar" separated by noise characters in a string, like "basdldfnmewoor", which should match 'bar' first, capitalized for emphasis: "basdldFnmewOOr"

It's guaranteed to contain one or both of "foo" or "bar" and all garbage characters are [a-z]

Here's my regex/function.

```
def first_foobar(mystring):
    foo = re.search("\w*?(f)\w*?(o)\w*?(o)|\w*?(b)\w*?(a)\w*?(r)",mystring)
    if foo.group(1) == "f":
        return("foo")
    else:
        return("bar")
```

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a more pythonic way to do this? It never seems to match the second regex after the |

Answer (score 1):

```
def first_foobar(mystring):
    foo = re.search("\w*?(f)\w*?(o)\w*?(o)|\w*?(b)\w*?(a)\w*?(r)",mystring)
    if foo.group(1) == "f":
        return("foo")
    elif foo.group(4) == "b":
        return("bar")
```

The `b` in `bar` will in `4th` group

Comment: I would use, `x = next(i for i in foo.groups() if i); if x == 'b': print 'bar' elif x == 'f': print 'foo'`

Comment: @AvinashRaj yeah we can do that but i guess OP needs to understand `b` and `f` will not be in `group(1)`

Comment: then you need to explain why `b` exists in 4th group. ie, group 1,2,3 defined before `b` (group 4) is NOne.

Comment: @AvinashRaj i will if OP asks...as of now i feel it is self explanatory

Comment: Hi, thank you for your responses. I understand. I was thinking that (1) would be the first character of the regex it matched, but it's treating everything like one big regex, so the b a r are in 4, 5, and 6.

Comment: @BramletA yes so `group 1 2 3` are none